# Meteor AutoForm Field Divs

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

When autoform renders a field using afQuickField it wraps it in two divs with a class of 'input-field' and 'form-group' respectively. Is there a way to change this wrapping behaviour? This looks ok when using bootstrap, however, the CSS framework I'm using requires different classes.

Comment: What css framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how I missed this in the documentation, but I found [the solution](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#creating-a-custom-template). I also came across [a package](https://atmospherejs.com/gildaspk/autoform-materialize) that adds these templates for materialize.